# Freemarker рекурсивное отображение из таблицы

Tags: рекурсия, spring-boot, freemarker

Всем привет, пытаюсь сделать отображение на сайте сообщений из таблицы рекурсивно... Сейчас, как видно по скрину работает, но в шаблоне, жесткий хардкод, который отображает максимум 2 вложения, подскажите как написать правильную рекурсию, чтобы отображал сколько угодно вложений и не хардкодить так.

[image: Сейчас сделал вот так.]

[image: Таблица]

шаблон.ftl

```
<#list comment as msg>
    <#if !msg.reply??>
        <li>
            ${msg.message}
            <ul>
                <li>
            <#list replyes as reply>
                <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString()>
                    ${reply.message}
                    <#list replyes as sub_reply>
                        <#if sub_reply.reply.toString() == reply.toString()>
                            <ul>
                                <li>
                                    ${sub_reply.message}
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </#if>
                    </#list>
                </#if>

            </#list>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </#if>
</#list>
```

Controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "chat")
public String charPage(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user,
                       Map<String, Object> model) {
    model.put("comment",commentRepo.findAllByMessageIsNotNullOrderById());
    model.put("replyes",commentRepo.findAllByReplyIsNotNull());

    return "chatmessage";
}
```

Repo:

```
public interface CommentRepo extends JpaRepository <Comment, Long> {
  List<Comment> findAllByMessageIsNotNullOrderById();
  List<Comment> findAllByReplyIsNotNull();
}
```

Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long id;

private String message;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "comment_id")
private Comment reply;


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
private User user;


public Comment() {
}
```

Пытался писать макрос, но страница падает.

```
        <#list comment as msg>
    <#if !msg.reply??>
        <li>
            ${msg.message}
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <@treeView msg, replyes/>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </#if>
</#list>

<#macro treeView msg listReply>
  <#list listReply as reply>
    <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString>
        ${reply.message}
    <@ treeView reply, replyes/>
    </#if>
  </#list>
</#macro>
```

Comment: почему заминусили мой вопрос? он не нес стремление разобраться? или если я сам нашёл решение своей проблемы мне не нужно было указывать это? ведь это может оказаться полезным кому-нибудь другому

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Вот рабочий макрос для рекурсивного отображения данных из таблицы.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOkVy.png)

```
   <#list comment as msg>
    <#if !msg.reply??>
        <li>
            ${msg.message}
                <@treeView msg replyes/>
        </li>
    </#if>
</#list>

<#macro treeView msg listReply>
<#list listReply as reply>
    <#if reply.reply.toString() == msg.toString()>
    <ul>
        <li>
            ${reply.message}
                <@treeView reply replyes/>
        </li>
    </ul>
    </#if>
</#list>
</#macro>
```